# Android-NDK-Profiler -pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible

Tags: android-ndk, profiling, profiler

I am trying to build the example project for Android-NDK-Profiler: https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/

I was able to successfully able to ndk-build the library. When I am trying to add the library into the example project i keep getting a clash of flags.

`arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: -pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible`

I went through some of the old issues posted and the work around is: `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pg -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-function-sections` which gives me reference not exsist errors.

Please guide me through the correct set of flags.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking with a set of static libraries, make sure you add `android-ndk-profiler` as

`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android-ndk-profiler`

with the `+=` and not the `:=` as noted in the documentation.